# Recursive JSON typescript does not accept variables in node value

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Type script and I'm trying to generate an object having this shape:

```
users {

  "user1" : {

    "startDate" : <timestamp1>

  }

  "user2" : {

    "startDate" : <timestamp2>

  }
```

}
So I wrote this :

```
  type JSONValue =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | { [x: string]: JSONValue }
    | { JSONValue }
    | Array<JSONValue>;

  let sessions: JSONValue = [];
  let obj: JSONValue = {
      this.loggedUser.getName() :
        { "startDate": new Date().getTime() }
    }
```

The problem that the code does not compile because it doesn't accept the property : this.loggedUser.getName(), If I put a constant string it works.
The other problem I can't create a json object **users {}**, I can create only an array this is why I used push...

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to use brackets when computing property names with the object initializer syntax. This is a javascript specification and has nothing to do with Typescript

You should be able to do this:

```js
let obj: JSONValue = {
    [this.loggedUser.getName()]: { "startDate": new Date().getTime() }
};
```

See MDN docs on [Object initializer > Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

Comment: thank you it works and just a last question do you have an idea why I can not create a json object like this users { } I oncly can create an array Ithought that this part to it  JSONValue =
...    | { JSONValue }
    | Array<JSONValue>;